# Left Join 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I got 3 different tables (table1,table2,table3), and I need to perform percentage and frequency operations and output a HTML table.

Table1

```
CatCodes1 | CatCodes2 | CatCodes3
----------+-----------+----------
75287     | 20220     | 65656
78922     | 20852     | 56666
75287     | 20220     | 62892
78922     | 20852     | 55665
```

Table2: Should only pull results tested =1

```
AllCatCodes  | Tested
-------------+---------
75287        |  1
78922        |  0
75287        |  0
78922        |  0
20220        |  1
62892        |  1
20852        |  NULL
65656        |  1
```

Table 3

```
CodesCatAll | 
------------+
75287       |  
56666       |  
65656       |  
20220       |
```

I need to out put a table that looks like this

```
CatCode1(tab1) | % of CatCode(tab1) | Freq in All CatCode(tab2) | Percentage(tab2) | Freq in CodesCatAll(tab3) | Percentage(tab3) |
   75287
   78922     
   78992      
   Total          100%                     xxx                        100%            yyy                             100%
```

Below is the code that I have written to get catcode1 and %of catCode(table1). Question is how do I add the other two tables and the frequencies.

```
$sqlCom = "select CatCodes1, CAST(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over()"; 
$sqlCom .= " AS DECIMAL(18,2)) from table1 group by CatCodes1";
```

Comment: have you tried UNION ALL? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this. You need to do the calculations as sub-queries. In addition, you need an inner query that will calculate how many records are included in your dataset. Then have an outer query to join everything together.

**[Original SQL Fiddle HERE.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce57b2/37)**
**[Updated SQL Fiddle HERE.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce57b2/38)**
**[Third updated SQL Fiddle HERE.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce57b2/40)**

```
SELECT t1.CatCodes1 AS 'CatCode1(tab1)', t1.myPercent AS '% of CatCode(tab1)',
  ISNULL(t2.CountOfAllCatCodes, 0) AS 'Freq in All CatCode(tab2)',
  CASE 
    WHEN ttl.t2Ttl = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE CAST(ISNULL(t2.CountOfAllCatCodes, 0) * 100.0/ttl.t2Ttl AS DECIMAL(18,2))
  END AS 'Percentage(tab2)',
  ISNULL(t3.CountOfCodesCatAll, 0) AS 'Freq in CodesCatAll(tab3)',
  CASE 
    WHEN ttl.t3Ttl = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE CAST(ISNULL(t3.CountOfCodesCatAll, 0) * 100.0/ttl.t3Ttl AS DECIMAL(18,2))
  END AS 'Percentage(tab3)'
FROM (
  SELECT CatCodes1, CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS myPercent
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY CatCodes1
) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT AllCatCodes, COUNT(*) AS CountOfAllCatCodes, CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS myPercent2
  FROM table2
  WHERE ISNULL(Tested, 0) = 1
  GROUP BY AllCatCodes
) t2 ON t1.CatCodes1 = t2.AllCatCodes
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT CodesCatAll, COUNT(*) AS CountOfCodesCatAll, CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS myPercent3
  FROM table3
  GROUP BY CodesCatAll
) t3 ON t1.CatCodes1 = t3.CodesCatAll
CROSS JOIN (
  --Calculate total records which are matched...
  SELECT SUM(ISNULL(t2.CountOfAllCatCodes, 0)) as t2Ttl, SUM(ISNULL(t3.CountOfCodesCatAll, 0)) AS t3Ttl
  FROM (
    SELECT CatCodes1
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY CatCodes1
  ) t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT AllCatCodes, COUNT(*) AS CountOfAllCatCodes
    FROM table2
    WHERE ISNULL(Tested, 0) = 1
    GROUP BY AllCatCodes
  ) t2 ON t1.CatCodes1 = t2.AllCatCodes
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CodesCatAll, COUNT(*) AS CountOfCodesCatAll
    FROM table3
    GROUP BY CodesCatAll
  ) t3 ON t1.CatCodes1 = t3.CodesCatAll
) ttl
```

NOTE: For some reason SQL Fiddle is calculating the 'Percentage(tab2)' field as zero. I have checked up and down the code and can't find an error on my part and, as you can see, 'Percentage(tab3)' is written the exact same way and evaluating correctly. You can also see that the CountOfAllCatCodes evaluates to 2, and the ttl.t2Ttl is 4, which should give a result of 50%. So, I dunno.

To fill in the xxx and yyy fields on your page, either keep a running total as you build the table, or reference the t2Ttl and t3Ttl fields respectively.

**EDIT:** I figured out why some of the percents were returning zero. It was an assumed type casting problem. Notice the original calculation of percents is like this:

```
ISNULL(t2.CountOfAllCatCodes, 0)/ttl.t2Ttl * 100.0
```

So, INTEGER/INTEGER * DECIMAL --> [TRUNCATED INTEGER] * DECIMAL --> DECIMAL.
Or, using numbers: 2/4 * 100.0 --> 0 * 100.0 --> 0.

By switching the formula just slightly, I change the assumed data type:

```
ISNULL(t2.CountOfAllCatCodes, 0) * 100.0/ttl.t2Ttl
```

Or, if we wanted to, we could make it explicit using a CAST or CONVERT statement on the formula.

To answer the questions raised in your comment:

How do I stop null values from showing from table 1?

To solve this, any time you are selecting from Table1, add a WHERE clause into the SQL testing for NULL. Assuming you don't want NULL values on the CatCodes1 field, it would something like this:

```
SELECT [whatever]
FROM Table1
WHERE CatCodes1 IS NOT NULL
```

Can you please explain to me what the query is doing? Like the case statements, cross joins, and we have 4 left outter joins.

Now you are getting into basic SQL theory which is probably way out of scope for the original question, but here goes:

The CASE statement is used to evaluate multiple possibilities for a field based on various conditions. See [this link for Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) on the CASE statement. In this situation, I used a CASE statement to prevent a "division by zero" error. You see, if the denominator value EVER has the possibility of being zero, we want to be sure that we prevent this error by testing for zero before we actually perform the calculation. If it was available, I would just use an IF type statement: If the denominator is zero, return zero, otherwise numerator/denominator. Since SQL does not have an inline IF statement, we use the CASE statement instead.

The CROSS JOIN is something you need to be VERY careful with, but was appropriate in this case. I could easily calculate how many records in each table matched t1.CatCodes1, and I could easily count how many records existed in the t2 and t3 tables, but I was having trouble getting an accurate number of *matched* records only. To solve this problem, I did a separate query that counted only matched records (the ttl table). Then I CROSS JOIN to this table so that every row in our query has access to the calculations. The ttl table is used as the denominator to calculate percentage of total matched records.

LEFT OUTER JOINs are used to get all rows in one table, and only rows that match in the second table. Honestly, I was guessing if this was the proper join in this case. It is a little safer than an INNER JOIN because as long as the record exists in our primary table, we will see the results in our dataset. However, if we used an INNER JOIN, then the ID would need to exist in ALL THREE tables in order to show up in our results. You can find more [info about LEFT OUTER JOINS here...](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Let me know if you need any other explanation of what the SQL is doing...

Comment: Yeah for some reason i am not getting the percentage for both the tables. Kinda weird. MY SQL skills are low. Trying to acquire them, but can get them overnight :(

Comment: I figured out the reason for the zeroes and updated the code. This should help you with your problem.

Comment: WOW you are a genius. Yes, I got few questions. What are these ttl.t2Ttl and what exactly are they doing? Also, the percentages are not rounding up to 2 decimal places. There are two additional columns with same values what are they for? Also, are we using the tested = 1 condition for table 2? It is like where tested = 1

Comment: Genius is a bit much. I'm sure there's some true genius out there who could solve this query in three lines or something.

Comment: Anyway, to your questions: You stated that the Percent fields should not be based on a count of all records in the 2 and 3 tables, only the MATCHING records in the 2 and 3 tables. Therefore, the job of the ttl.t2Ttl field is to determine how many records in Table2 are matched so we can get an accurate percentage that adds up to 100%. The columns at the end (from ttl.*) were only for testing purposes as I was trying to work through why the calculation was returning as zero when I knew it shouldn't be.

Comment: And to round to 2 decimal places, just CAST or CONVERT on the outer SELECT similarly to how we are doing so in the inner SELECTs. There is no TESTED = 1 condition because I missed that in the original requirements. I'll update the SQL based on these...

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, how do I stop null values from showing from table 1? Also, can you please explain to me what the query is doing? Like the case statements, cross joins, and we have 4 left outter joins. Thanks. Sorry to bug you so much

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will do the trick... You need to do the calculations as sub-queries and have an outer query to join everything together.

**[SQL Fiddle here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce57b2/11)**

```
SELECT t1.CatCodes1 AS 'CatCode1(tab1)', t1.myPercent AS '% of CatCode(tab1)',
  ISNULL(t2.CountOfAllCatCodes, 0) AS 'Freq in All CatCode(tab2)', ISNULL(t2.myPercent, 0) AS 'Percentage(tab2)',
  ISNULL(t3.CountOfCodesCatAll, 0) AS 'Freq in CodesCatAll(tab3)', ISNULL(t3.myPercent, 0) AS 'Percentage(tab3)'
FROM (
  SELECT CatCodes1, CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS myPercent
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY CatCodes1
) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT AllCatCodes, COUNT(*) AS CountOfAllCatCodes, CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS myPercent
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY AllCatCodes
) t2 ON t1.CatCodes1 = t2.AllCatCodes
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT CodesCatAll, COUNT(*) AS CountOfCodesCatAll, CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS myPercent
  FROM table3
  GROUP BY CodesCatAll
) t3 ON t1.CatCodes1 = t3.CodesCatAll
```

Comment: percentagefrom tab2 should add up to 100% using Freq in All CatCode(tab2). Same thing for percentage in tab3 (adds up to 100%) using Freq in CodesCatAll(tab3).
Sorry if it was not clear. I edited my question little bit so that it is clear

Comment: Also how do i get the xxx and the yyy for the last row

Comment: So the percentage in "Percentage(tab2)" should not include all rows in Table2, but only the JOINED rows in Table2? Hmmm, that is more complicated.

Comment: Yes, it will only contain the rows that are common to table1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this page http://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/sqlaz/jointures/
I'm sorry, it's in french, but reading the code containing "join" might help you.

At first, just try to extract data on 3 tables without any calculation.
And show :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

then when the result table is ok, add calculation.